# Infinitely loading gem (requires subgems)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm sorry for the title, as I'm really not sure how to describe it. Basically, I have a set of gems I built, named conventionally as "mygems-gem1", "mygems-gem2", etc.

I decided it would be a lot easier if I made another gem, "mygems", that would require all of the child gems (i.e. "mygems-gem1", etc).

I tried this, built and installed the gem, and loaded up IRB. But, requiring "mygems" now just sits forever and never loads anything. Seems like a dependency conflict, maybe?

What's really strange is that I can load up IRB and require the child gems by hand and that works perfectly.

What gives?

**EDIT:** Letting it continue running, it never raises an error. I don't know if this is of any help, but upon CTRL+Cing out, I get this stack trace:

`` from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:62:in `call'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in contains_requirable_file?'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:62:in `each'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:62:in `any?'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:62:in `block in contains_requirable_file?'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:60:in `each'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:60:in `any?'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:60:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:951:in `block (2 levels) in find_in_unresolved_tree'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2397:in `[]'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2397:in `block (2 levels) in traverse'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2396:in `each'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2396:in `block in traverse'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2395:in `each'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2395:in `traverse'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2398:in `block (2 levels) in traverse'
... 17 levels...
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:93:in `require'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/method_source-0.8.2/lib/method_source.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry.rb:124:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mygems-gem1-0.12.8/lib/mygems/gem1.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/mygems-0.0.1/lib/mygems.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/kinginky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>' ``

Answer (score 0):

> I tried this, built and installed the gem, and loaded up IRB.

You don't need to build a gem for that. What if you just make a ruby script with

```
require "mygems-gem1"
require "mygems-gem2"
...
```

And `require` that? Does that work?

Comment: Sure, that's what I was doing before. The reason I wanted to do it this way was I was going to put all specs for the overall application, and I need to include all the gems for that. This works fine in my specs (oddly), which are in the "mygems" gem, but I get the loading issue if I try to load that gem in IRB or a script.